# Merge git branches with different roots

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I have 2 svn converted git repositories.
One of them has turned a subdirectory into a new git repositoy, like this:

```
/filea
/fileb
```

The second repository is from the entire trunk, like this:

```
/roota
/rootb
/subdirectory/filea
/subdirectory/fileb
```

I now want to merge all the changes made to the second repository's `subdirectory` folder into the first repository, ignoring any changes to its root.

How can this be done? I've read a bit about read-tree and such, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up cherry-picking the commits that only changed the files I had in my first repository. Git was clever enough to detect the different paths while doing so.